# Jquery to send HTML of page in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.ModelBase>" %>

<div>
<img id="ExportToExcelExposure" style=" cursor: pointer;" src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/btn_user_export_excel_off.gif")%>" />
    <table id="exposureTable">
        <tr>
            <td id="exposureLabel">
                Standard Deviations
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExposureStdDev,
                                Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.DropDownData.ExposureStdDev(),
                                new { propertyName = "ExposureStdDev" })%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <hr />
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="exposureButton" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <img src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/chic/btn_calculate.gif")%>" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <table id="results2">
            <tr>
                <td id="header" colspan="2" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="table" />
                <td id="graph" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

What would the JQuery be to make an AJAX call to my controller and send the body of my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
$.post("test.php", $("body").html());
```

See the [documentation for `jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more information.